# Can I change the HTTP response status in an $http Interceptor?

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor

I'm trying to create an Angular 1 app on top of a SAML secured backend.
When I issue a REST request while not authenticated, I get a response with status 200 and an HTML page that will submit a page to the IDP.

I don't want this 200 response to reach my `$http(...).then(function(...){})` method in my services.
So I want to change the 200 to a 401 status code in an HTTP interceptor.

Is that possible?

Any alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it:

In the response method, you can use this statement to set the status to 401:

```
return $q.reject({status: 401, error: 'UNAUTHORIZED'});
```

Full code-sample:

```
interceptor = function ($q, $location, $rootScope) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                ...
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            requestError: function (rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            response: function (response) {

                if (response.status === 200 &&
                    response.headers()['content-type']==='text/html' &&
                    response.data.startsWith("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>SAML HTTP Post Binding</TITLE>")) {
                    //WE HAVE A SAML AUTH REQUEST
                    return $q.reject({status: 401, error: 'UNAUTHORIZED'});
                }

                return response;
            },

            responseError: function (rejection) {
                ...
            }

        };
    };
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Comment: I got this error ```Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection``` when calling ```$q.reject(..)```.